# pgfplots axis labels in wrong place after scaling

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When using the `scale` key for `tikzpicture`, the `axis` labels of `pgfplots` are no longer in the correct place.  In the example below, the first `axis` environment is *not* within a scaled `tikzpicture` environment and the `axis` labels are placed correctly.  The second `axis` environment is in a scaled `tikzpicture` environment and the `axis` labels are *not* placed correctly.  The third `axis` environment has the same problem even when the `transform shape` key is given to the scaled `tikzpicture` environment.

How can I scale the `tikzpicture` environment and still get the `axis` labels to appear in the correct positions?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, axis lines=center]
   % empty
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}\\
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, axis lines=center]
   % empty
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}\\
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
  \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, axis lines=center]
   % empty
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `scale=.5` and `transform shape` to the local axis options, like:

```
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, axis lines=center, scale=.5, transform shape]
```

Here's how it looks:

[image: figure 1]