# Pgfplots axis labels misplaced (half page away from the grid)

Tags: pgfplots, labels, axis

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{tyyli/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=0.5ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, xshift=0.5ex}}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[tyyli,xtick={-10,-8,...,10}, ytick={-10,-8,...,10},
xmin=-10, xmax=10 , ymin=-10, ymax=10, grid=both]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that x label is nowhere and y label is at the top of the page when the picture is at the bottom.

[image: coordinate plane with misplaced axis label]

Comment: Welcome! Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` to the preamble of your file.

Comment: Also note that `pgfplots` already loads `tikz`

Comment: Related Question: [How to properly scale a TikZ/PGF picture which has a `\begin{axis}…\end{axis}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17438/4301).  Similar behavior, different cause (as there is no known fix, except to run it multiple times]: [PGFplot Axis Labels Detaching From Graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18658/4301).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [pgfplots axis labels in wrong place after scaling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243884/pgfplots-axis-labels-in-wrong-place-after-scaling)

The basic idea is to delete the `[scale=2]` argument from `\begin{tikzpicture}` and add `scale=2` to the axis arguments.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=0.5ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, xshift=0.5ex}}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} % don't put [scale=2] here
    \begin{axis}[xtick={-10,-8,...,10}, ytick={-10,-8,...,10},
    xmin=-10, xmax=10 , ymin=-10, ymax=10, grid=both, axis lines=center, ylabel={$y$}, xlabel={$x$}, scale=2]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked, I wouldn't have guessed it was about scaling!